Difference between PopulateObject and DeserializeObject (Newtonsoft JSON)
I'm wondering what the difference is between the two functions.
It seems they achieve the same thing except DeserializeObject will zero out any existing values in the target object if they aren't present in the given JSON string, while PopulateObject preserves existing values.

DeserializeObject always creates a new object of a specified type and populates it with JSON data. Even if you have an existing object with some values, calling DeserializeObject will discrd that object and create a new one based on the JSON data.
PopulateObject updates an existing object with data from JSON. It will only modify properties that are specified in the JSON, leaving other properties untouched.
